# The method getFontMetrics(Font) is undefined for the type infoPanel

Tags: java, eclipse

Hello guys I am trying to add a score counter from one panel to a different panel. I have copy and pasted the code but am getting this error message. The method getFontMetrics(Font) is undefined for the type infoPanel. The 'getFontMetrics' is the only part underlined in red

```
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    if (running) {

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 40));
        FontMetrics metrics3 = getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
        g.drawString("Score: " + applesEaten, (SCREEN_WIDTH - metrics3.stringWidth("Score: " + applesEaten)) / 2, g.getFont().getSize());
    }
}
```

Comment: The error means that infoPanel doesn't have a method called getFontInfo(). I believe that this is a method of Graphics.

Comment: @NomadMaker ok cool thank u very much, will u please write the line of code that i must enter? I can not find the g.getFontInfo()

Comment: Sorry, I meant g.getFontMetrics().

Comment: @NomadMaker thanks for the help but I am still having trouble. I am very new to coding

Comment: Sorry you're having troubles. Please read the javadocs for Graphics. I find them by using ``google java Graphics docs``.

Comment: *I am very new to coding* - you can't code if you don't have a reference to the API. You need access to the API so you can find the methods of each Object. If you use an IDE the IDE should have access to the API. If you don't use an IDE then you need to manually download the API. You can find the API documentation download link on the Oracle website where you downloaded the JDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad idea to create the `Font` inside the draw call, because each time it's called, you'll create a new `Font`. You should instead put this into an instance variable or create it in the constructor, and simply reference it from there.

You can then also pass that font instance into the `getFontMetrics` call.

The real problem here is that the `getFontMetrics` is a method on the `Graphics` object, and you've not called it here. You'll need to use `g.getFontMetrics(font)` instead.

Comment: thank you for the help! I will revisit that game and use the info you have provided